# Does turning off FireBase swizzling affect analytics besides push receipts?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

The [Firebase cloud messaging documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client) says that they swizzle some methods in order to get a push notification token and log receiving a push notification. In the [FIRAnalytics documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseanalytics/interface_f_i_r_analytics#a91dab50fdb82112d6620f3036bdf6455), some event names are reserved (see under `logEventName:parameters:`), including `in_app_purchase`. This suggests that Firebase is automatically logging in-app purchases to their analytics, which seems difficult to do automatically without swizzling.

Does Firebase swizzle in order to use these reserved keywords? If so, does turning off swizzling via `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` disable these analytics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, setting FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO will disable the swizzling of the App Delegate methods only. It will not affect in app purchase events since Analytics does not get in app purchase events from your App Delegate. As mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseanalytics/category_f_i_r_analytics_07_app_delegate_08), the only thing that will affect Analytics is campaign events through opening app with URLs/Universal Links. If you decide to turn it off while you still want support for campaign events, it is recommended to add the methods as described in the documentation.

Comment: This property seems to not be working for me.  I set it in the plist, and it's still telling me it's auto creating the proxy.

Comment: Which plist are you adding to? Is it the Info.plist or GoogleService-Info.plist? Note that it should be Info.plist. The value should be a boolean, not a string.