# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is not getting called Swift 5, Xcode 10.2

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

`didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` and `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` is not getting called on real device.

This what i have tried so far:

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert, .sound]) {
            (granted, error) in
            if granted {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                    //UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            } else {
                //print("APNS Registration failed")
                //print("Error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            }
        }
    } else {
        let type: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
        let setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: type, categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(setting)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        //UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
```

Then the register and fail method:

```
private func application(application: UIApplication,
                 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken as Data
    print("Registered Notification")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {

        print(error.localizedDescription)
        print("Not registered notification")
}
```

Note:

> - I have tried it on real device not neither of the methods are getting called.
> - I have tried on simulator if the code is working or not, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError is getting called
>     with error.(Which means code is fine)
> - I have double checked the certificates and regenerated the provisioning file after turning on the push notifications in
>     capabilities.
> - I have also added background modes -> remote notifications on.
> - I have tried with legacy build also no luck.
> - I have tried reinstalling apps many times not working.
> - FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled is set to NO in plist still no luck.
> - Also updated the pods still no luck.

Comment: if you are using FCM , have you check this method called`func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String)`

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya FCM token i am receiving but i am not able to register tried everything. Yes, i have tried that also it is working but other methods not working.

Comment: Not sure but because of method swizzling  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38985061/does-turning-off-firebase-swizzling-affect-analytics-besides-push-receipts

Comment: If you are usingFCM then you are getting FCM token in Messaging delegate method  send to your server . What else you need ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya How will i enable the push notifications then it is also not working?. I tried with firebase console send message service to send notification with FCM token, it is not receiving either.

Comment: Have you uploaded the p12 file to firebase console ?, If not then it is must

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya yes that is the first thing i did when i started to work on push notifications

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192297/discussion-between-harjot-singh-and-prashant-tukadiya).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we discussed on Chat. Firebase use method swizzling so  you will get token in  `func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String)` method instead of   `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`

You have to make sure following things

1) Correct Certificate for Prod. and Dev.

2) Must upload certi. to firebase console

3) Must implement  UNUserNotificationCenter's Delegate method

4) make sure you have implemented `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)`

5) make sure you have a line `completionHandler()` at bottom of the function

Hope it is helpful

Comment: it solves the problem for a sometime, but the notification is not still receiving when the firebase token is refreshed i tried many times to send notification still the same case? I am getting feeling seems like Apple bug?

Comment: I think in real case senario this will not happen. Because when you get new token. you will send to the server so server has latest token all time. Apple doesn't promise instant delivery of push notification util it is voip push. so we can't blame apple on this.

Comment: right now i am testing the push notifications with firebase send message it started working when i have installed the app after 1 day which is today, i know we can't blame apple in this, seems like a some bug to me. I will send to the server the latest token when this bug resolves.

Answer (score 4):

Weird Solution but it worked for me. After trying for hours, I just turn off and on the wifi from the device setting app and it worked.

Comment: Thanks! this help me. And I noticed that after turning ON the wifi again I see a lot of callbacks to didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken. It seems that the requests got stuck and only did work after turning OFF and ON the wifi.

Comment: Really Weird!!! but it worked for me too.. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this problem out!!
I have no idea why this works, but it works, here is my action:

1. Add some print in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method and keep devices connected.
2. Enter https://developer.apple.com/
   Choose Account -> Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> Keys
3. Select the key of your project, click "edit", and close (don't save)
4. See the log from Xcode, I see many print from didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken

Comment: Hi @codeeer, thanks for the answer but I have solved it by letting the firebase swizzle its methods by keeping FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to YES.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I tried same after switching off and on the wifi and it worked.
I was using a vpn for connecting to a particular development server. So when I switch off and on the wifi the vpn gets disabled and connection become normal.

I don't know whether this was the exact issue but when I tried through the vpn the "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" didn't get executed and on disabling vpn everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You must add Push Notifications to the capabilities in Xcode or you will get this error: no valid “aps-environment” entitlement string found for application