# Device token not generate iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, devicetoken

I tried much time but not called the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method.  I have spent a lot of time. Please let me know me if anyone has a solution.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data){

     let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
}
```

Below function used for register notification in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate`.

```
    func registerNotification(application:UIApplication) -> Void {

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *){
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert], completionHandler: {(granted, error) in
                if (granted)
                {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                    }
                }
                else{
                    print("Noti Not registered !!")
                    //Do stuff if unsuccessful...
                }
            })
        }
        else { //If user is not on iOS 10 use the old methods we've been using
            let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(
                types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not everything ends with success. [Handle fail too](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622962-application) and check what's happening there.

Comment: @user28434 I have checked this `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` not called and not throw any error there.

Comment: see this for help : [didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is not getting called Swift 5, Xcode 10.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55823643/didregisterforremotenotificationswithdevicetoken-is-not-getting-called-swift-5)

Comment: Try restarting your device, it happens with me as well. This is common among Xcode deployment and Adhoc as well, sometimes you need to wait some time up to 1 hour before it works fine again.

Answer (score 1):

Apply Following Code for Notification Permission

1. Enable Background Modes in Signing & Capabilities

[image]

2. In `AppDelegate`

```
    self.registerForPushNotifications(application: application)
```

```
    func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {

            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

                let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                    options: authOptions,
                    completionHandler: {_, _ in })
            } else {
                let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                    UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
                application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            }

            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        }

        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
            let token = deviceToken.description().trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "<>"))

            strDeviceToken = token.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        }
```