# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not called

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications

I have the following approach to get my UID for push notifications. Sadly, it's not being called. What I'm doing wrong? The registration for the push notifications is working. The error func is not being called. I'am getting crazy here.

```
extension AppDelegate {
    
    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

        // 1. Convert device token to string
        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data -> String in
            return String(format: "%02.2hhx", data)
        }
        let token = tokenParts.joined()
        // 2. Print device token to use for PNs payloads
        print("Device Token: \(token)")

        }
    
    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error registering notifications: (error)")
    }
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
        AppearanceConfigurator.configureNavigationBar()
        UIFont.overrideInitialize()
        
        
        requestNotificationAuthorization()
        print ("prepared for push notifications ...")
        
        return true
}

func getNotificationSettings() {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
                print("User Notification settings: (settings)")
                guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                    print ("registred for push notifications")
                }
            }
        }
        
        func requestNotificationAuthorization(){
            // Request for permissions
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                .requestAuthorization(
                options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
                    [weak self] granted, error in
                    //print("Notification granted: (granted)")
                    guard granted else { return }
                    self?.getNotificationSettings()
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you enabled **Remote notifications** under TARGETS -> Signing $ Capabilities -> Background Modes

Comment: yes, I've added Remote Notifications under Background Modes

Comment: same issue [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55823643/didregisterforremotenotificationswithdevicetoken-is-not-getting-called-swift-5). Try any of this, hope it fixes the issue.

Comment: nothing helped so far, checked your link above

Comment: ok, I think I got the issue. You have a typo, missing a _ ,correct the method to **func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)**

Answer (score 21):

Adding for anybody else who feels intractibly stuck on this issue with a SwiftUI app; e.g. your code looks good, provisioning profiles are configured, etc etc etc, but still getting no response when calling UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications() from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in the AppDelegate...

what fixed it in my case was to add the following in my plist:

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<false/>
```

Comment: This worked for me too. Guess in SwiftUI if you're using Firebase Messaging in the app, we need to disable swizzling and handle it manually. After disabling this to make sure FCM still works I had to manually set the device token to Firebase FCM. 
  ```Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken```

For more inforamtion visit this link. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#token-swizzle-disabled

Comment: So much time lost because of this... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the **didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken** method. You are using the wrong method name.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print("Successfully registered for notifications!")
}
```

Comment: indeed, it's working now. I am so thankful. Well, I use this website https://www.pushtry.com to test and I get the error "one or more device tokens do not belong to this bundle id". Any idea?

Comment: Are you getting the device id now?

Comment: yes I got it, thanks

Comment: it stopped working ... I corrected the above mentioned typo error but the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken ist never called

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you did not add the `Push Notifications` capability in the `Signing & Capabilities` tab of your target.